# How do I update the state to trigger render change in async promise callback?

Tags: javascript, react-native

I'm seeing some behaviour that I don't understand, I have a helper class that accepts a reference to the parent, to be able to update the state:

```
let appUpdate = new AppUpdate(this);
appUpdate.getUpdate();
```

In this class there is a function that returns like so:

```
return Promise.all(updatePromises);
```

But the important part is I'm setting the state in the callback to each promise:

```
for(const promise of promises)
    {
        promise.then(() => {

            this.app.setState(prevState => ({progress: prevState.progress+1}));
        });
    }
```

I would expect this to update the state to increment progress by 1 whenever a promise is resolved, but instead what I am seeing is: I can output the progress and see it update in console but "prevState" is always undefined, it also doesn't update in the render function to trigger the progress bar update.

I'm wondering what might cause a difference in what is resolved in the render function and outputted in console log.

Full example:

```
class App extends Component {
    constructor() {
        super();

        this.state = {
            progress: 0,
        }

        let appUpdate = new AppUpdate(this);
        appUpdate.getUpdate().then(() => {
            console.log("Update successful");
        });
    }

    render()
    {
        // Correctly outputs progress
        console.log(this.state.progress);

        return (
            <View>
                
                <Text>
                    // Stays as 0 until just just before they all finish
                    { this.state.progress }
                </Text>

            </View>
        );
    }
}

class AppUpdate
{
    app = null;

    constructor(app)
    {
        this.app = app;
    }

    async getUpdate()
    {
        // At this point updatePromises is confirmed to be an array of around 100 promises
        let updatePromises = [];

        for(const promise of updatePromises)
        {
            promise.then(() => {

                // This outputs progress gradually incrementing until it reaches the last promise resolve, the same as in the main class
                console.log(this.app.state.progress);

                this.app.setState(prevState => ({progress: prevState.progress+1}));
            });
        }

        return Promise.all(updatePromises);
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you certain that 'this' is the same in both cases, i.e. that the same element is being talked about? A bit more code showing where you make the console.log call and where the if is would be helpful.

Comment: @AHaworth Yes I am passing the "this" from the parent component to the AppUpdate class and I can console.log the state.progress in both the promise callback and in the render method and they both output correctly. I'll update the question with more code.